# How to read the Inspect Element data in a browser using a script

Tags: javascript, json, macos, safari-web-inspector

So when I right click and go to "Inspect Element" in Safari, I can navigate to the following under the Source tab:

[image: Safari Inspect Element Sources Tab]

The website in question, Instagram, updates the webpage with chunks of json that can be seen as the "/" files under the GraphQL/query "folder". From within safari I can do a bunch of things from the GUI with each individual list. I can open each one of those "/" files in a new tab to see that yes, indeed, they are json files. I can copy as link, copy as a curl command, copy as HTTP Request or Response. The only thing I can't seem to do is get at this data with any kind of script! Is there any way of coaxing these elements out of ANY browser?

Edit:
My main goal is to download photos from Instagram that include all of the metadata for that photo, which is only available from the JSON data that they send to the browser.

Comment: You could try to make the same http request in the scripting language of your choice.

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @charlietfl trying to get the json updates that are sent to the browser. The ultimate goal is to download some photos and include all the metadata that is included with each photo. If I just scrapped the webpage for the pictures, I would miss all of that metadata that is in the JSON.